# how to read the junk character value from json file using java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I need to read the JSON file and make changes using the content. the content contains the file path that needs to be accessed. it worked fine. Now the file path has junk characters

for eg:
original file name = c:/hgjfiâ€™s seven-step.docx
file name after the execution = c:/hgjfiÃ¢â‚¬â„¢s seven.docx

it throwing "file not found exception". I need to read the file with the junk characters. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
    try {
      json = args[0];
      int count = 0;
      String firstFile = "";
      JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
      JSONObject jsonObject;
      try {
        logger.info("*---------START---------*");
        JSONArray a = (JSONArray)parser.parse(new FileReader(json));
        for (Object o : a) {
          JSONObject order = (JSONObject)o;
          if (count == 0) {
            firstFile = FilenameUtils.getName((String)order.get("FilePath"));
            firstFile = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(firstFile);
          } 
}
```

Comment: You need to read the file containing the json in the correct encoding otherwise that silly file name with its complex characters will not be read correctly. You are currently assuming it's been encoded in the default encoding of the machine on which you're running that code. If you post the actual file somewhere, I'll take a look.

Comment: hi @g00se please find the JSON : [{"FilePath":"C:\Title Page.docx","DuplicatePercentage":6.118665},{"FilePath":"C:\Revised Manuscript.docx","DuplicatePercentage":0.26271793},{"FilePath":"C:\Table 2 Characteristics of the participants.docx","DuplicatePercentage":0.0},{"FilePath":"C:\Table 3 Analysis application of Colaizziâ€™s seven-step.docx","DuplicatePercentage":0.4385965}]

Comment: Hang on - you're passing that actual string as `args[0]`?

Comment: And an online formatter is telling me that json is invalid

Comment: This is full json : [{"FilePath":"C:\\Users\\e503824\\Desktop\\Sample\\Title Page.docx","DuplicatePercentage":6.118665},{"FilePath":"C:\\Users\\e503824\\Desktop\\Sample\\Revised Manuscript.docx","DuplicatePercentage":0.26271793},{"FilePath":"C:\\Users\\e503824\\Desktop\\Sample\\Table 2 Characteristics of the participants.docx","DuplicatePercentage":0.0},{"FilePath":"C:\\Users\\e503824\\Desktop\\Sample\Table 3 Analysis application of Colaizziâ€™s seven-step.docx","DuplicatePercentage":0.4385965}]

Comment: i'm taking json as a args[0] (Argument)

Comment: `FileReader` ctor is expecting a file name, not json. If you are passing actual json you need to use a `StringReader` (and obvs. make sure the json string is valid)

Comment: JSONArray a = (JSONArray)parser.parse(new FileReader(json));      while reading this file Table 3 Analysis application of Colaizziâ€™s seven-step.docx directly through Exception

Comment: You're confusing me. Can you tell me **a**. The *actual* value of `args[0]` and **b** which line of that code is throwing the exception?